# loopback postgresql date without timestamp node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

Hi i am very new to loopback postgresql connector. I need date datatype without timezone.

Now my model.json is as follows:

```
"properties": {
    "start_date": {
      "type": "date",      
      "required": true
    },
    "end_date": {
      "type": "date",      
      "required": true
    },
    "amount": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
   "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "amount_saved": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  }
```

Now the date is storing as `2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z` but i need 2015-02-01 to be stored.. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks dude,, but when i retrieving it shows the same {
  "start_date": "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "end_date": "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "amount": 79000,
  "description": "To buy a 1000cc bike",
  "amount_saved": 34000,
  "id": 1
}

Answer (score 0):

Use the database mapping to achieve this. You can then map to a native data type - for instance [here are the PostgreSQL date/time datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html).

In your example, you just need to map the field to the PostgreSQL `date` data type:

```
"start_date": {
  "type": "date",
  "required": true,
  "postgresql": {
    "columnName": "StartDate",
    "dataType": "date",
    "dataLength": null,
    "dataPrecision": null,
    "dataScale": null,
    "nullable": "YES"
  }
}
```

Comment: now its storing as 2015-02-01 05:30:00.. but i need 2015-02-01

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can anyone please help.

Database is having - 2022-12-15
Fetched in node.js as - 2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
Returned to API - 2022-12-15T00:00:00.000Z

Expected - 2022-12-15